# How to prove Span of 2 vectors is same as span of a combination of those vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\mathrm{Span}[\vec{a}, \vec{b}] = \mathrm{Span}[\vec{2a}+\vec{3b}, \vec{2a} − \vec{b}]$.

How to go about solving this question?
Read some notes but still don't get it yet.

Appreciate any tips/guidance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know the definition of span? If so, how can you express an arbitrary vector from the span of $\{x+y,x-y\}$?

Comment: One way to prove that two sets $A$ and $B$ have the same span is to show that every element of $A$ is in the span of $B$ and that every element of $B$ is in the span of $A$. But it is extremely important that you also understand why that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

What does span mean? The span of a set $A$ is the set of all linear combinations of elements from $A$.

Now from that definition, it suffices to show you can write everything in $\{x,y\}$ as a linear combination of things in $\{x+y, x-y\}$ and vice versa. Well

$$x = 0.5(x+y) + 0.5(x-y), \:\:\: y = 0.5(x+y) + -0.5(x-y)  $$
and
$$x+y = 1x + 1y,\:\:\: x-y = 1x + -1y $$